# I don't know how to fix this hover effect

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a hover effect where words appear over the hero section when the mouse hovers over it. If you uncomment the code at the bottom of the CSS file you will see that the code works just fine. The only problem is the backround picture dispears and turns completely white. I don't know how to fix it.

Uncomment the code all the way at the bottom of the CSS to see what I'm talking about

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Kumbh Sans", sans-serif;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
  }
  
  .navbar {
    background: #131313;
    height: 60px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 555;
  }
  
  .navbar__container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between; 
    height: 80px;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 20px;
  }
  
  #navbar__logo {
    background-color: #ff8d02;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 2rem;
  }

  #trade {
    background-color: #0045f2;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 13px;
    bottom: 6px; 
    
  }
  
  .navbar__menu {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    list-style: none;
  }
  
  .navbar__item {
    height: 80px;
  }
  
  .navbar__links {
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 120px;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 100%;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }
  
  .navbar__btn {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 1rem;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .button {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #833ab4;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, rgb(240, 105, 2), #8c8393, #4d7fff);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(240, 105, 2), #8c8393, #4d7fff);
    color: #fff;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }

  .navbar__btn:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    
    border-radius: 4px;
    transition: all 1s ease;
  }  
  
  .navbar__links:hover {
    color: #ff7802;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }

  
  @media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
    .navbar__container {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      height: 80px;
      z-index: 1;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 1300px; 
      padding: 0;
    }
  
    .navbar__menu {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: auto;
      margin: 0;
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: -1000px;
      opacity: 1;
      transition: all 0.5s ease;
      z-index: -1;
    }
  
    .navbar__menu.active {
      background: #131313;
      top: 100%;
      opacity: 1;
      transition: all 0.5s ease;
      z-index: 99;
      height: 60vh;
      font-size: 1.6rem;
    }
  
    #navbar__logo {
      padding-left: 25px;
    }
  
    .navbar__toggle .bar {
      width: 25px;
      height: 3px;
      margin: 5px auto;
      transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
      background: #fff;
    }
  
    .navbar__item {
      width: 100%;
    }
  
    .navbar__links {
      text-align: center;
      padding: 2rem;
      width: 100%;
      display: table;
    }
  
    .navbar__btn {
      padding-bottom: 2rem;
    }
  
    .button {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      width: 80%;
      height: 80px;
      margin: 0;
    }
  
    #mobile-menu {
      position: absolute;
      top: 20%;
      right: 5%;
      transform: translate(5%, 20%);
    }

    .navbar__toggle .bar {
      display: block;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    #mobile-menu.is-active .bar:nth-child(2) {
      opacity: 0;
    }

    #mobile-menu.is-active .bar:nth-child(1) {
      transform: translateY(8px) rotate(45deg);
    }

    #mobile-menu.is-active .bar:nth-child(3) {
      transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
    }
}

/* Hero Section */

.hero {
  padding: 50px 0;
  background-image: url(./images/brooke-cagle-g1Kr4Ozfoac-unsplash.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background-position: top;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}


.hero__heading {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 100px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #000000c4;
}

.orange {
  color: rgb(255, 89, 0);
}

.main__btn {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

.main__btn a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
}

.button__color {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #1e5dff, rgb(255, 89, 0) );
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #1e5dff,  rgb(255, 89, 0));
}

/*
.hero_two {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
}

.hero_two > * {
  transform: translateY(20px);
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
}

.hero_two:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.hero_two:hover {
  transform: translateY(0);
} */
```

````html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Pigeon</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.14.0/css/all.css"
      integrity="sha384-HzLeBuhoNPvSl5KYnjx0BT+WB0QEEqLprO+NBkkk5gbc67FTaL7XIGa2w1L0Xbgc"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-SZXxX4whJ79/gErwcOYf+zWLeJdY/qpuqC4cAa9rOGUstPomtqpuNWT9wdPEn2fk" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Navbar Section -->
    <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar__container">
          <a href="#home" id="navbar__logo">Pigeon<small id="trade">TRADE</small></a>
          <div class="navbar__toggle" id="mobile-menu">
            <span class="bar"></span> 
            <span class="bar"></span>
            <span class="bar"></span>
          </div>
          <ul class="navbar__menu">
            <li class="navbar__item">
              <a href="#home" class="navbar__links" id="home-page">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="navbar__item">
              <a href="#about" class="navbar__links" id="about-page">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="navbar__item">
              <a href="#services" class="navbar__links" id="services-page">Services</a>
            </li>
            <li class="navbar__btn">
              <a href="#sign-up" class="button" id="signup">Sign Up</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Hero Section -->
    <div class="hero_two hero" id="home">
        <div class="hero__container">
            <div class="image__overlay">
                <div class="hero__content">
                    <h1 class="hero__heading">Get started <br>making your <span class="orange">online <br>business</span> today!</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main__btn">
            <button class="button button__color"><a href="#">Explore</a></button>
        </div>
    </div>

```
````

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Please add only relevant part of the code

Comment: @NicoHaase I'm just confused as to why hero picture keeps disappearing when I get the code to work, you literally have to uncomment all the parts of the CSS that say .hero_two to understand what I'm talking about.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, along with your attempts to resolve the problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are overwriting the `background-image` property value from `.hero` when you add `background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);` for `.hero_two`

Use instead `background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);`

The property `background` is a shorthand for all background properties including background-image.

> The background shorthand CSS property sets all background style properties at once, such as color, image, origin and size, or repeat method.

Read more here -> [background property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background)

See below

EDIT after comments:

You are using two classes on the SAME element. If you write some styles for `hero_two` it will overwrite the styles for `hero`. because you are selecting the same element.

If I understand correctly, you want to show an 'overlay' and make the text appear when hovering. You can use a `pseudo-element` for that ( `:after` in this case) and some tweaks in your css styling. ( Remove the `hero_two` classname because it's useless )

```css
/* Hero Section */

.hero {
  padding: 50px 0;
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/150");
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background-position: top;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}


.hero__heading {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 100px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #000000c4;
}

.orange {
  color: rgb(255, 89, 0);
}

.main__btn {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

.main__btn a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
}

.button__color {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #1e5dff, rgb(255, 89, 0));
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #1e5dff, rgb(255, 89, 0));
}

.hero:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.hero * {
  transform: translateY(20px);
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
  opacity: 0;
}

.hero:hover * {
  transform: translateY(0px);
  color: #ffffff;
  opacity: 1;
}

.hero:hover:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero_two hero" id="home">
   <div class="hero__container">
     <div class="image__overlay">
       <div class="hero__content">
         <h1 class="hero__heading">Get started <br>making your <span class="orange">online <br>business</span> today!</h1>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="main__btn">
     <button class="button button__color"><a href="#">Explore</a></button>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Next time please share only relevant code ( eg. navbar has nothing to do with this ) and take the time to make a code snippet like the one above that reproduces your problem. ( For images, please use a placeholder as we cannot use your own images 'cause we don't have them )

happy coding.

Comment: It still didn't quite work.. The background image disappears until the mouse hovers over it, I didn't want the background image to disappear at all, I just wanted the text to disappear and re-appear. But we are close to figuring it out.

Comment: i did, you don't have the picture so I don't thin you can see what I'm talking about. The picture that I have saved to the background-image property in .hero also disappears. I didn't want that to happen. I just want the hover effect on the text, not the background image.

Comment: @YuriMckoy in my answer, the picture does not disappear .... I have a placeholder picture which does NOT disappear on hover. Isn't that right ?